# Collect all the items in a form in jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, collections

How do I collect all the checkboxes and dropdown list items in jQuery for saving?

Comment: *Large correlation* between the questions - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1186309/11236

Answer (score 10):

Or, for recent versions of jquery you can use:

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/serialize - to a URL encoded string `person.name=john&person.age=20`

or

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/serializeArray - to JSON

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use the jQuery [Form](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) plugin, like this:

```
$('#myFormId').formSerialize();
```

From the [formSerialize API documentation](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#api):

```
Serializes the form into a query string. This method will return a string in the format: name1=value1&name2=value2
```

Comment: how to pass `.formSerialize()` results to `ajaxSubmit()`?

Answer (score 2):

$('#myFormId').formSerialize(); is a plugin and maybe not necessary. 
The core function serialize() is better.

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/serialize

Comment: My view state is also visible when I am doing a .serialize