# Convert form data to JavaScript object with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, serialization

How do I convert all elements of my form to a JavaScript object?

I'd like to have some way of automatically building a JavaScript object from my form, without having to loop over each element. I do not want a string, as returned by `$('#formid').serialize();`, nor do I want the map returned by `$('#formid').serializeArray();`

Comment: because the first returns a string, exactly like what you'd get if you submitted the form with a GET method, and the second gives you a array of objects, each with a name value pair. I want that if i have a field named "email" i get an object that will allow me to retrieve that value with obj.email. With serializeArray(), i'd have to do something like obj[indexOfElement].value

Answer (score 1736, accepted):

[serializeArray](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) already does exactly that. You just need to massage the data into your required format:

```js
function objectifyForm(formArray) {
    //serialize data function
    var returnArray = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < formArray.length; i++){
        returnArray[formArray[i]['name']] = formArray[i]['value'];
    }
    return returnArray;
}
```

Watch out for hidden fields which have the same name as real inputs as they will get overwritten.

Comment: Do you mean "why use serializeArray to get the data in the first place?" Because serializeArray is already written, is unit tested in multiple browsers, and could theoretically be improved in later versions of jQuery. The less code you write that has to access inconsistent things like DOM elements directly, the more stable your code will be.

Comment: Be warned, serializeArray() will not include disabled elements.  I often disable input elements that are sync'd to other elements on the page, but I still want them included in my serialized object.  You're better off using something like `$.map( $("#container :input"), function(n, i) { /* n.name and $(n).val() */ } );` if you need to include disabled elements.

Comment: multiple name only return last one.

Comment: Doesn't work for multi dimensional array

Answer (score 471):

## Convert forms to JSON *like a boss*

---

The current source is my [on GitHub](https://github.com/macek/jquery-serialize-object) and [Bower](https://bower.io/).

> $ bower install jquery-serialize-object

---

#### The following code is now **deprecated**.

The following code can take work with all sorts of input names; and handle them just as you'd expect.

For example:

```
<!-- All of these will work! -->
<input name="honey[badger]" value="a">
<input name="wombat[]" value="b">
<input name="hello[panda][]" value="c">
<input name="animals[0][name]" value="d">
<input name="animals[0][breed]" value="e">
<input name="crazy[1][][wonky]" value="f">
<input name="dream[as][vividly][as][you][can]" value="g">
```

```js
// Output
{
  "honey":{
    "badger":"a"
  },
  "wombat":["b"],
  "hello":{
    "panda":["c"]
  },
  "animals":[
    {
      "name":"d",
      "breed":"e"
    }
  ],
  "crazy":[
    null,
    [
      {"wonky":"f"}
    ]
  ],
  "dream":{
    "as":{
      "vividly":{
        "as":{
          "you":{
            "can":"g"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Usage

```
$('#my-form').serializeObject();
```

### The Sorcery (JavaScript)

```
(function($){
    $.fn.serializeObject = function(){

        var self = this,
            json = {},
            push_counters = {},
            patterns = {
                "validate": /^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*(?:\[(?:\d*|[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\])*$/,
                "key":      /[a-zA-Z0-9_]+|(?=\[\])/g,
                "push":     /^$/,
                "fixed":    /^\d+$/,
                "named":    /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/
            };


        this.build = function(base, key, value){
            base[key] = value;
            return base;
        };

        this.push_counter = function(key){
            if(push_counters[key] === undefined){
                push_counters[key] = 0;
            }
            return push_counters[key]++;
        };

        $.each($(this).serializeArray(), function(){

            // Skip invalid keys
            if(!patterns.validate.test(this.name)){
                return;
            }

            var k,
                keys = this.name.match(patterns.key),
                merge = this.value,
                reverse_key = this.name;

            while((k = keys.pop()) !== undefined){

                // Adjust reverse_key
                reverse_key = reverse_key.replace(new RegExp("\\[" + k + "\\]$"), '');

                // Push
                if(k.match(patterns.push)){
                    merge = self.build([], self.push_counter(reverse_key), merge);
                }

                // Fixed
                else if(k.match(patterns.fixed)){
                    merge = self.build([], k, merge);
                }

                // Named
                else if(k.match(patterns.named)){
                    merge = self.build({}, k, merge);
                }
            }

            json = $.extend(true, json, merge);
        });

        return json;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: So, that works pretty well.  But it's misnamed: it doesn't return JSON, as the name implies.  Instead, it returns an object literal. Also, it's important to check for hasOwnProperty, otherwise your arrays have anything that's attached to their prototype, like: {numbers: ["1", "3", indexOf: function(){...}]}

Answer (score 314):

What's wrong with:

```
var data = {};
$(".form-selector").serializeArray().map(function(x){data[x.name] = x.value;});
```

Comment: `$(this).serializeArray().reduce(function(m,o){  m[o.name] = o.value; return m;}, {})`

Comment: `$(this).serializeArray().reduce((o,kv) => ({...o, [kv.name]: kv.value}), {})`

Comment: this is the one row solution, though others work too.

Comment: You mean other than the fact that this doesn't support form arrays?

Answer (score 107):

A fixed version of Tobias Cohen's solution. This one correctly handles falsy values like `0` and `''`.

```
jQuery.fn.serializeObject = function() {
  var arrayData, objectData;
  arrayData = this.serializeArray();
  objectData = {};

  $.each(arrayData, function() {
    var value;

    if (this.value != null) {
      value = this.value;
    } else {
      value = '';
    }

    if (objectData[this.name] != null) {
      if (!objectData[this.name].push) {
        objectData[this.name] = [objectData[this.name]];
      }

      objectData[this.name].push(value);
    } else {
      objectData[this.name] = value;
    }
  });

  return objectData;
};
```

And a CoffeeScript version for your coding convenience:

```
jQuery.fn.serializeObject = ->
  arrayData = @serializeArray()
  objectData = {}

  $.each arrayData, ->
    if @value?
      value = @value
    else
      value = ''

    if objectData[@name]?
      unless objectData[@name].push
        objectData[@name] = [objectData[@name]]

      objectData[@name].push value
    else
      objectData[@name] = value

  return objectData
```

Answer (score 70):

I like using `Array.prototype.reduce` because it's a one-liner, and it doesn't rely on [Underscore.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underscore.js) or the like:

```
$('#formid').serializeArray()
    .reduce(function(a, x) { a[x.name] = x.value; return a; }, {});
```

This is similar to the answer using `Array.prototype.map`, but you don't need to clutter up your scope with an additional object variable. One-stop shopping.

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: Forms with inputs that have duplicate `name` attributes are valid HTML, and is actually a common approach. Using any of the answers in this thread will be inappropriate in that case (since object keys must be unique).

Answer (score 47):

## [UPDATE 2020]

With a simple oneliner in vanilla js that leverages [fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) (as always, check browser support):

```js
Object.fromEntries(new FormData(form))
```

Comment: doesn't handle nested form notation into json.

Comment: Obviously as it is not considered as valid html https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-form-element, even chromium remove nested form

Comment: Perfect answer.

Comment: Thank you So Much, work for flat Model

Comment: I spent a fair bit of time trying to make this work, and in case it helps others; make sure your inputs have names as well as ids, and name your form. Here is the entire line to return JSON ready to send via AJAX:  const my_form_data = JSON.stringify( Object.fromEntries( new FormData( document.forms.namedItem( "my-form-name" ) ) ) );

Comment: @CraigJacobs They don't need IDs, just names. And the form itself doesn't need a name if you have a different way of accessing it.

Answer (score 29):

All of these answers seemed so over the top to me. There's something to be said for simplicity. As long as all your form inputs have the name attribute set this should work just jim dandy.

> ```
> $('form.myform').submit(function () {
>   var $this = $(this)
>     , viewArr = $this.serializeArray()
>     , view = {};
>
>   for (var i in viewArr) {
>     view[viewArr[i].name] = viewArr[i].value;
>   }
>
>   //Do stuff with view object here (e.g. JSON.stringify?)
> });
> ```

Answer (score 25):

### I checked that there is a problem with all the other answers, that if the input name is as an array, such as `name[key]`, then it should be generated like this:
`name:{ key : value }`

---

**For example:** If you have an HTML form similar to the one below:

```html
<form>
    <input name="name" value="value" >
    <input name="name1[key1]" value="value1" >
    <input name="name2[key2]" value="value2" >
    <input name="name3[key3]" value="value3" >
</form>
```

But it should be generated just like the JSON below, and does not become an object like the following with all the other answers. So if anyone wants to bring something like the following JSON, try the JS code below.

```json
{
    name  : 'value',
    name1 : { key1 : 'value1' },
    name2 : { key2 : 'value2' },
    name3 : { key2 : 'value2' }
}
```

```js
$.fn.getForm2obj = function() {
  var _ = {};
  $.map(this.serializeArray(), function(n) {
    const keys = n.name.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+|(?=\[\])/g);
    if (keys.length > 1) {
      let tmp = _;
      pop = keys.pop();
      for (let i = 0; i < keys.length, j = keys[i]; i++) {
        tmp[j] = (!tmp[j] ? (pop == '') ? [] : {} : tmp[j]), tmp = tmp[j];
      }
      if (pop == '') tmp = (!Array.isArray(tmp) ? [] : tmp), tmp.push(n.value);
      else tmp[pop] = n.value;
    } else _[keys.pop()] = n.value;
  });
  return _;
}
console.log($('form').getForm2obj());
$('form input').change(function() {
  console.clear();
  console.log($('form').getForm2obj());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input name="name" value="value">
  <input type="checkbox" name="name1[]" value="1" checked="checked">1
  <input type="checkbox" name="name1[]" value="2">2
  <input type="checkbox" name="name1[]" value="3">3<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked="checked">male
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> female
  <input name="name2[key1]" value="value1">
  <input name="one[another][another_one]" value="value4">
  <input name="name3[1][name]" value="value4">
  <input name="name3[2][name]" value="value4">
  <input name="[]" value="value5">
</form>
```

Comment: This answer does cover the case mentioned, but it does not cover cases like checkbox[] or even one[another][another_one]

Comment: @LeonardoBeal i fix my ans .. check this now ..!

Comment: I am the downvoter and I downvoted because `eval` should not be used in this way because `eval`, when used in this way, promotes terribly unreliable, buggy, illperformant, and potentially unsecure practices.

Comment: I can't agree this is a good answer. And please when you write answers make your code self-explanatory or explain it. `this.c = function(k,v){ eval("c = typeof "+k+";"); if(c == 'undefined') _t.b(k,v);}` is short und not explanatory. A dev with less experience will just copy this without understanding why and how it works.

Comment: @JackGiffin  Check out my new code now because I've removed `eval()` from my code.

Comment: @BhavikHirani After a long search, I found your answer, you saved me a long hours of search! thanks man!!

Comment: @BurhanKashour welcome anytime please don't forget to upvote !

Answer (score 24):

There really is no way to do this without examining each of the elements.  What you really want to know is "has someone else already written a method that converts a form to a JSON object?"   Something like the following should work -- note that it will only give you the form elements that would be returned via a POST (must have a name).  This is **not tested**.

```
function formToJSON( selector )
{
     var form = {};
     $(selector).find(':input[name]:enabled').each( function() {
         var self = $(this);
         var name = self.attr('name');
         if (form[name]) {
            form[name] = form[name] + ',' + self.val();
         }
         else {
            form[name] = self.val();
         }
     });

     return form;
}
```

Comment: This function returns an object not a JSON string.

Answer (score 23):

If you are using [Underscore.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underscore.js) you can use the relatively concise:

```
_.object(_.map($('#myform').serializeArray(), _.values))
```

Comment: I am not certain how it worked previously, but now it does not. Changed a bit that works: `Object.fromEntries(_.map($('#myform').serializeArray(), _.values))`

Answer (score 20):

Ok, I know this already has a highly upvoted answer, but another [similar question was asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277655/how-to-convert-jquery-serialize-data-to-json-object/3277710#3277710) recently, and I was directed to this question as well.  I'd like to offer my solution as well, because it offers an advantage over the accepted solution:  You can include disabled form elements (which is sometimes important, depending on how your UI functions)

Here is my answer from the [other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277655/how-to-convert-jquery-serialize-data-to-json-object/3277710#3277710):

Initially, we were using jQuery's `serializeArray()` method, but that does not include form elements that are disabled.  We will often disable form elements that are "sync'd" to other sources on the page, but we still need to include the data in our serialized object.  So `serializeArray()` is out.  We used the `:input` selector to get all input elements (both enabled and disabled) in a given container, and then `$.map()` to create our object.

```
var inputs = $("#container :input");
var obj = $.map(inputs, function(n, i)
{
    var o = {};
    o[n.name] = $(n).val();
    return o;
});
console.log(obj);
```

Note that for this to work, each of your inputs will need a `name` attribute, which will be the name of the property of the resulting object.

That is actually slightly modified from what we used.  We needed to create an object that was structured as a .NET IDictionary, so we used this: (I provide it here in case it's useful)

```
var obj = $.map(inputs, function(n, i)
{
    return { Key: n.name, Value: $(n).val() };
});
console.log(obj);
```

I like both of these solutions, because they are simple uses of the `$.map()` function, and you have complete control over your selector (so, which elements you end up including in your resulting object).  Also, no extra plugin required.  Plain old jQuery.

Comment: I tried this in a project, using `map` like this creates an array of objects with a single property, it does not collapse the properties all into one object.

Answer (score 17):

This function should handle multidimensional arrays along with multiple elements with the same name.

I've been using it for a couple years so far:

```
jQuery.fn.serializeJSON=function() {
  var json = {};
  jQuery.map(jQuery(this).serializeArray(), function(n, i) {
    var _ = n.name.indexOf('[');
    if (_ > -1) {
      var o = json;
      _name = n.name.replace(/\]/gi, '').split('[');
      for (var i=0, len=_name.length; i<len; i++) {
        if (i == len-1) {
          if (o[_name[i]]) {
            if (typeof o[_name[i]] == 'string') {
              o[_name[i]] = [o[_name[i]]];
            }
            o[_name[i]].push(n.value);
          }
          else o[_name[i]] = n.value || '';
        }
        else o = o[_name[i]] = o[_name[i]] || {};
      }
    }
    else {
      if (json[n.name] !== undefined) {
        if (!json[n.name].push) {
          json[n.name] = [json[n.name]];
        }
        json[n.name].push(n.value || '');
      }
      else json[n.name] = n.value || '';      
    }
  });
  return json;
};
```

Answer (score 15):

One-liner (no dependencies other than jQuery), uses fixed object binding for function passsed to `map` method.

```
$('form').serializeArray().map(function(x){this[x.name] = x.value; return this;}.bind({}))[0]
```

What it does?

```
"id=2&value=1&comment=ok" => Object { id: "2", value: "1", comment: "ok" }
```

suitable for progressive web apps (one can easily support both regular form submit action as well as ajax requests)

Answer (score 14):

You can do this:

```
var frm = $(document.myform);
var data = JSON.stringify(frm.serializeArray());
```

See *[JSON](http://www.json.org/)*.

Comment: The question is how to get an object not a JSON string.

Answer (score 11):

Use:

```
function form_to_json (selector) {
  var ary = $(selector).serializeArray();
  var obj = {};
  for (var a = 0; a < ary.length; a++) obj[ary[a].name] = ary[a].value;
  return obj;
}
```

Output:

```
{"myfield": "myfield value", "passwordfield": "mypasswordvalue"}
```

Answer (score 7):

From some [older](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17784656/1197775) answer:

```
$('form input, form select').toArray().reduce(function(m,e){m[e.name] = $(e).val(); return m;},{})
```

Comment: From what I can tell, the difference is that your solution does not depend on `serializeArray` so you have the freedom to choose whatever inputs you want (eg. you can include disabled inputs), right? I.e. this is not coupled to any form or the submit event, it's just independent by itself?

Comment: the only small difference with linked answer is that there is no data needed to instantiate, `reduce` returns the object.

This is not independent since `toArray` is from jQuery.

Answer (score 6):

I found a problem with Tobias Cohen's code (I don't have enough points to comment on it directly), which otherwise works for me. If you have two select options with the same name, both with value="", the original code will produce "name":"" instead of "name":["",""]

I think this can fixed by adding " || o[this.name] == ''" to the first if condition:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] || o[this.name] == '') {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};
```

Answer (score 6):

Simplicity is best here. I've used a simple string replace with a regular expression, and they worked like a charm thus far. I am not a regular expression expert, but I bet you can even populate very complex objects.

```
var values = $(this).serialize(),
attributes = {};

values.replace(/([^&]+)=([^&]*)/g, function (match, name, value) {
    attributes[name] = value;
});
```

Answer (score 6):

```
const formData = new FormData(form);

let formDataJSON = {};

for (const [key, value] of formData.entries()) {

    formDataJSON[key] = value;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Using [maček's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery/8407771#8407771), I modified it to work with the way ASP.NET MVC handles their nested/complex objects on the same form. All you have to do is modify the validate piece to this:

```
"validate": /^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*((?:\[(?:\d*|[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\])*(?:\.)[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)*$/,
```

This will match and then correctly map elements with names like:

```
<input type="text" name="zooName" />
```

And

```
<input type="text" name="zooAnimals[0].name" />
```

Comment: This looks like a reply to an answer, not a self contained answer to the question.

Answer (score 5):

the simplest and most accurate way i found for this problem was to use [bbq plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) or this [one](https://github.com/chrissrogers/jquery-deparam) (which is about 0.5K bytes size).

**it also works with multi dimensional arrays.**

```js
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
 return $.deparam(this.serialize());
};
```

Comment: This does seem to work nicely. There's [an alternative repository for jquery-deparam](https://github.com/AceMetrix/jquery-deparam) that includes description files for bower and npm.

Answer (score 4):

There is a plugin to do just that for jQuery, *[jquery.serializeJSON](https://github.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON)*. I have used it successfully on a few projects now. It works like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

Another answer

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    var form = document.getElementById('form') || document.querySelector('form[name="userprofile"]');
    var json = Array.from(new FormData(form)).map(function(e,i) {this[e[0]]=e[1]; return this;}.bind({}))[0];
    
    console.log(json)
    document.querySelector('#asJSON').value = JSON.stringify(json);
  }, 1000);
})
```

```html
<form name="userprofile" id="form">
  <p>Name <input type="text" name="firstname" value="John"/></p>
  <p>Family name <input name="lastname" value="Smith"/></p>
  <p>Work <input name="employment[name]" value="inc, Inc."/></p>
  <p>Works since <input name="employment[since]" value="2017" /></p>
  <p>Photo <input type="file" /></p>
  <p>Send <input type="submit" /></p>
</form>

JSON: <textarea id="asJSON"></textarea>
```

FormData: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Answer (score 3):

I prefer this approach because: you don't have to iterate over 2 collections, you can get at things other than "name" and "value" if you need to, and you can sanitize your values before you store them in the object (if you have default values that you don't wish to store, for example).

```
$.formObject = function($o) {
    var o = {},
        real_value = function($field) {
            var val = $field.val() || "";

            // additional cleaning here, if needed

            return val;
        };

    if (typeof o != "object") {
        $o = $(o);
    }

    $(":input[name]", $o).each(function(i, field) {
        var $field = $(field),
            name = $field.attr("name"),
            value = real_value($field);

        if (o[name]) {
            if (!$.isArray(o[name])) {
                o[name] = [o[name]];
            }

            o[name].push(value);
        }

        else {
            o[name] = value;
        }
    });

    return o;
}
```

Use like so:

```
var obj = $.formObject($("#someForm"));
```

Only tested in Firefox.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a one-liner using **[reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)**.  Reduce is a functional function that takes the return value of the passed function and passes it back to the passed function in the next iteration, along with the nth value from the list.

```
$('#formid').serializeArray().reduce((o,p) => ({...o, [p.name]: p.value}), {})
```

We have to use a few of tricks to get this to work:

- `...o` (spread syntax) inserts all the `key: value` pairs from `o`
- Wrap the object we are returning in `()` to distinguish it from the `{}` that denote a function
- Wrap the key (`p.name`) in `[]`

Comment: I get wrong result if I don't add a init-object to that function: $('form').serializeArray().reduce((o, p) => ({...o, [p.name]: p.value}), {})

Comment: This has been fixed by Pluto. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Taking advantage of ES6 goodness in a one liner:

```js
$("form").serializeArray().reduce((o, {name: n, value: v}) => Object.assign(o, { [n]: v }), {});
```

Answer (score 3):

## Serialize Deep Nested Forms **Without JQuery**

After spending a couple of days looking for a solution to this problem that has no dependencies, I decided to make a non-jQuery form data serializer, using the FormData API.

The logic in the serializer is largely based on the de-param function from a jQuery plugin called jQuery BBQ, however, all dependencies have been removed in this project.

This project can be found on NPM and Github:

https://github.com/GistApps/deep-serialize-form

https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-serialize-form

```
function deepSerializeForm(form) {

  var obj = {};

  var formData = new FormData(form);

  var coerce_types = { 'true': !0, 'false': !1, 'null': null };

  /**
   * Get the input value from the formData by key
   * @return {mixed}
   */
  var getValue = function(formData, key) {

    var val = formData.get(key);

    val = val && !isNaN(val)              ? +val              // number
        : val === 'undefined'             ? undefined         // undefined
        : coerce_types[val] !== undefined ? coerce_types[val] // true, false, null
        : val;                                                // string

    return val;
  }

  for (var key of formData.keys()) {

    var val  = getValue(formData, key);
    var cur  = obj;
    var i    = 0;
    var keys = key.split('][');
    var keys_last = keys.length - 1;


    if (/\[/.test(keys[0]) && /\]$/.test(keys[keys_last])) {

      keys[keys_last] = keys[keys_last].replace(/\]$/, '');

      keys = keys.shift().split('[').concat(keys);

      keys_last = keys.length - 1;

    } else {

      keys_last = 0;
    }


    if ( keys_last ) {

      for (; i <= keys_last; i++) {
        key = keys[i] === '' ? cur.length : keys[i];
        cur = cur[key] = i < keys_last
        ? cur[key] || (keys[i+1] && isNaN(keys[i+1]) ? {} : [])
        : val;
      }

    } else {

      if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {

        obj[key].push( val );

      } else if (obj[key] !== undefined) {

        obj[key] = [obj[key], val];

      } else {

        obj[key] = val;

      }

    }

  }

  return obj;

}

window.deepSerializeForm = deepSerializeForm;
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: FormData constructor: Argument 1 does not implement interface HTMLFormElement.` I don't understand

Answer (score 2):

I like samuels version, but I believe it has a small error. Normally JSON is sent as

> {"coreSKU":"PCGUYJS","name_de":"whatever",...

NOT as

> [{"coreSKU":"PCGUYJS"},{"name_de":"whatever"},...

so the function IMO should read:

```
App.toJson = function( selector ) {
    var o = {};
    $.map( $( selector ), function( n,i )
    {
        o[n.name] = $(n).val();
    });     
    return o;
}
```

and to wrap it in data array (as commonly expected, too), and finally send it as astring
App.stringify( {data:App.toJson( '#cropform :input' )} )

For the stringify look at [Question 3593046](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593046) for the lean version, at [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) for the every-eventuality-covered version. That should cover it all :)

Comment: Thank you.. this makes (as you mentioned) tiny but very important difference.

Answer (score 2):

I found a problem with the selected solution.

When using forms that have array based names the jQuery serializeArray() function actually dies.

I have a PHP framework that uses array-based field names to allow for the same form to be put onto the same page multiple times in multiple views. This can be handy to put both add, edit and delete on the same page without conflicting form models.

Since I wanted to seralize the forms without having to take this absolute base functionality out I decided to write my own seralizeArray():

```
        var $vals = {};

        $("#video_edit_form input").each(function(i){
            var name = $(this).attr("name").replace(/editSingleForm\[/i, '');

            name = name.replace(/\]/i, '');

            switch($(this).attr("type")){
                case "text":
                    $vals[name] = $(this).val();
                    break;
                case "checkbox":
                    if($(this).attr("checked")){
                        $vals[name] = $(this).val();
                    }
                    break;
                case "radio":
                    if($(this).attr("checked")){
                        $vals[name] = $(this).val();
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        });
```

Please note: This also works outside of form submit() so if an error occurs in the rest of your code the form won't submit if you place on a link button saying "save changes".

Also note that this function should never be used to validate the form only to gather the data to send to the server-side for validation. Using such weak and mass-assigned code WILL cause [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), etc.

Answer (score 2):

**Turn anything into an object (not unit tested)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
string = {};

string.repeat = function(string, count)
{
    return new Array(count+1).join(string);
}

string.count = function(string)
{
    var count = 0;

    for (var i=1; i<arguments.length; i++)
    {
        var results = string.match(new RegExp(arguments[i], 'g'));
        count += results ? results.length : 0;
    }

    return count;
}

array = {};

array.merge = function(arr1, arr2)
{
    for (var i in arr2)
    {
        if (arr1[i] && typeof arr1[i] == 'object' && typeof arr2[i] == 'object')
            arr1[i] = array.merge(arr1[i], arr2[i]);
        else
            arr1[i] = arr2[i]
    }

    return arr1;
}

array.print = function(obj)
{
    var arr = [];
    $.each(obj, function(key, val) {
        var next = key + ": ";
        next += $.isPlainObject(val) ? array.print(val) : val;
        arr.push( next );
      });

    return "{ " +  arr.join(", ") + " }";
}

node = {};

node.objectify = function(node, params)
{
    if (!params)
        params = {};

    if (!params.selector)
        params.selector = "*";

    if (!params.key)
        params.key = "name";

    if (!params.value)
        params.value = "value";

    var o = {};
    var indexes = {};

    $(node).find(params.selector+"["+params.key+"]").each(function()
    {
        var name = $(this).attr(params.key),
            value = $(this).attr(params.value);

        var obj = $.parseJSON("{"+name.replace(/([^\[]*)/, function()
        {
            return '"'+arguments[1]+'"';
        }).replace(/\[(.*?)\]/gi, function()
        {
            if (arguments[1].length == 0)
            {
                var index = arguments[3].substring(0, arguments[2]);
                indexes[index] = indexes[index] !== undefined ? indexes[index]+1 : 0;

                return ':{"'+indexes[index]+'"';
            }
            else
                return ':{"'+escape(arguments[1])+'"';
        })+':"'+value.replace(/[\\"]/gi, function()
        {
            return "\\"+arguments[0]; 
        })+'"'+string.repeat('}', string.count(name, ']'))+"}");

        o = array.merge(o, obj);
    });

    return o;
}
</script>
```

The output of test:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    console.log(array.print(node.objectify($("form"), {})));
    console.log(array.print(node.objectify($("form"), {selector: "select"})));
});
```

on

```
<form>
    <input name='input[a]' type='text' value='text'/>
    <select name='input[b]'>
        <option>select</option>
    </select>

    <input name='otherinput[c][a]' value='a'/>
    <input name='otherinput[c][]' value='b'/>
    <input name='otherinput[d][b]' value='c'/>
    <input name='otherinput[c][]' value='d'/>

    <input type='hidden' name='anotherinput' value='hidden'/>
    <input type='hidden' name='anotherinput' value='1'/>

    <input type='submit' value='submit'/>
</form>
```

will yield:

```
{ input: { a: text, b: select }, otherinput: { c: { a: a, 0: b, 1: d }, d: { b: c } }, anotherinput: 1 }
{ input: { b: select } }
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem lately and came out with [this .toJSON jQuery plugin](https://gist.github.com/4055352) which converts a form into a JSON object with the same structure. This is also expecially useful for dynamically generated forms where you want to let your user add more fields in specific places.

The point is you may actually want to build a form so that it has a structure itself, so let's say you want to make a form where the user inserts his favourite places in town: you can imagine this form to represent a `<places>...</places>` XML element containing a list of places the user likes thus a list of `<place>...</place>` elements each one containing for example a `<name>...</name>` element, a `<type>...</type>` element and then a list of `<activity>...</activity>` elements to represent the activities you can perform in such a place. So your XML structure would be like this:

```
<places>

    <place>

        <name>Home</name>
        <type>dwelling</type>

        <activity>sleep</activity>
        <activity>eat</activity>
        <activity>watch TV</activity>

    </place>

    <place>...</place>

    <place>...</place>

</places>
```

How cool would it be to have a JSON object out of this which would represent this exact structure so you'll be able to either:

- Store this object as it is in any [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/)-like database
- Read it from your $_POST[] server side and retrive a correctly nested array you can then semantically manipulate
- Use some server-side script to convert it into a well-formed XML file (even if you don't know its exact structure a-priori)
- Just somehow use it as it is in any [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/)-like server script

OK, so now we need to think how a form can represent an XML file.

Of course the `<form>` tag is the `root`, but then we have that `<place>` element which is a container and not a data element itself, so we cannot use an input tag for it.

Here's where the `<fieldset>` tag comes in handy! We'll use `<fieldset>` tags to represent all container elements in our form/XML representation and so getting to a result like this:

```
<form name="places">

    <fieldset name="place">

        <input type="text" name="name"/>
        <select name="type">
            <option value="dwelling">Dwelling</option>
            <option value="restoration">Restoration</option>
            <option value="sport">Sport</option>
            <option value="administrative">Administrative</option>
        </select>

        <input type="text" name="activity"/>
        <input type="text" name="activity"/>
        <input type="text" name="activity"/>

    </fieldset>

</form>
```

As you can see in this form, we're breaking the rule of unique names, but this is OK because they'll be converted into an array of element thus they'll be referenced only by their index inside the array.

At this point you can see how there's no `name="array[]"` like name inside the form and everything is pretty, simple and semantic.

Now we want this form to be converted into a JSON object which will look like this:

```
{'places':{

    'place':[

        {

            'name': 'Home',
            'type': 'dwelling',

            'activity':[

                 'sleep',
                 'eat',
                 'watch TV'

            ]

        },

        {...},

        {...}

    ]

}}
```

To do this I have developed [this jQuery plugin here](https://gist.github.com/4055352) which someone helped optimizing in [this *Code Review* thread](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/13443/jquery-plugin-node-tojson-convert-html-form-to-js-object) and looks like this:

```
$.fn.toJSO = function () {
    var obj = {},
        $kids = $(this).children('[name]');
    if (!$kids.length) {
        return $(this).val();
    }
    $kids.each(function () {
        var $el = $(this),
            name = $el.attr('name');
        if ($el.siblings("[name=" + name + "]").length) {
            if (!/radio|checkbox/i.test($el.attr('type')) || $el.prop('checked')) {
                obj[name] = obj[name] || [];
                obj[name].push($el.toJSO());
            }
        } else {
            obj[name] = $el.toJSO();
        }
    });
    return obj;
};
```

I also made [this one blog post](http://poliradiolabs.altervista.org/?p=39&preview=true&preview_id=39&preview_nonce=576b7546ef) to explain this more.

This converts everything in a form to JSON (even radio and check boxes) and all you'll have left to do is call

```
$.post('script.php',('form').toJSO(), ...);
```

I know there's plenty of ways to convert forms into JSON objects and sure `.serialize()` and `.serializeArray()` work great in most cases and are mostly intended to be used, but I think this whole idea of *writing a form as an XML structure with meaningful names and converting it into a well-formed JSON object* is worth the try, also the fact you can add same-name input tags without worrying is very useful if you need to retrive dynamically generated forms data.

I hope this helps someone!

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

For a quick, modern solution, use the [JSONify](https://github.com/kushalpandya/JSONify) jQuery plugin. The example below is taken verbatim from the GitHub README. All credit to Kushal Pandya, author of the plugin.

Given:

```
<form id="myform">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name"/>
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email"/>
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password"/>
</form>
```

Running:

```
$('#myform').jsonify();
```

Produces:

```
{"name":"Joe User","email":"joe@example.com","password":"mypass"}
```

If you want to do a jQuery POST with this JSON object:

```
$('#mybutton').click(function() {
    $.post('/api/user', JSON.stringify($('#myform').jsonify()));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So I used the accepted answer and found a major flaw.
It doesn't support input arrays like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="array[]" value="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="array[]" value="2"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="array[]" value="3"/>
```

This minor change should fix that:

```
function objectifyForm(inp){
    var rObject = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < inp.length; i++){
        if(inp[i]['name'].substr(inp[i]['name'].length - 2) == "[]"){
            var tmp = inp[i]['name'].substr(0, inp[i]['name'].length-2);
            if(Array.isArray(rObject[tmp])){
                rObject[tmp].push(inp[i]['value']);
            } else{
                rObject[tmp] = [];
                rObject[tmp].push(inp[i]['value']);
            }
        } else{
            rObject[inp[i]['name']] = inp[i]['value'];
        }
    }
    return rObject;
}
```

Remember to pass it the output from `$(this).serializeArray();` otherwise it wont work.

Comment: Yes! So many upvoted answers, but only this one works properly with checkboxes. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Tobias's solution above is the correct one, however, as commenter @macek pointed out, it does not handle inputs of type foo[bar] and split them into sub-objects.

This is a PHP-only feature, but I still find it very useful to be able to generate the same structure in JavaScript.

I simply modified Tobias's code above, so all credit goes to him. This can probably be made cleaner, but I just whipped it up in five minutes and thought it might be useful.

It does not handle multidimensional arrays or numerically indexed arrays at this time. That is, it will only work with names foo[bar] and not foo[].

```
jQuery.fn.serializeObjectPHP = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var re = /^(.+)\[(.*)\]$/;
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    var n;
    jQuery.each(a, function() {
        var name = this.name;
        if ((n = re.exec(this.name)) && n[2]) {
            if (o[n[1]] === undefined) {
                o[n[1]] = {};
                o[n[1]][n[2]] = this.value || '';
            } else if (o[n[1]][n[2]] === undefined) {
                o[n[1]][n[2]] = this.value || '';
            } else {
                if(!o[n[1]][n[2]].push) {
                    o[n[1]][n[2]] = [ o[n[1]][n[2]] ];
                }
                o[n[1]][n[2]].push(this.value || '');
            }
        } else {
            if (n && !n[2]) {
                name = n[1];
            }
            if (o[name] !== undefined) {
                if (!o[name].push) {
                    o[name] = [o[name]];
                }
                o[name].push(this.value || '');
            } else {
                o[name] = this.value || '';
            }
        }
    });
    return o;
};
```

Comment: it seems as though you didn't read my entire comment.  I devised a solution that handles `foo[bar]`-type inputs as well as `foo[bar][bof][a][b][c][etc]`; see my answer in this thread.  Also note that `foo[bar]` "parsing" is not unique to PHP.  Rails heavily relies on this convention for passing form attributes to objects.

Answer (score 1):

using [lodash#set](https://lodash.com/docs#set)

```
let serialized = [
  { key: 'data[model][id]', value: 1 },
  { key: 'data[model][name]', value: 'product' },
  { key: 'sid', value: 'dh0un1hr4d' }
];

serialized.reduce(function(res, item) {
  _.set(res, item.key, item.value);
  return res;
}, {});

// returns
{
  "data": {
    "model": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "product"
    }
  },
  "sid": "dh0un1hr4d"
}
```

Comment: I like this solution, but it doesn't handle form fields in `key[]` array format; `[ {key: 'items[]', value: 1 }, {key: 'items[]', value: 2 } ]` results in `{ items: { "": 2  } }`.

Answer (score 1):

A more modern way is to use reduce with `serializeArray()`  in this way:

```
$('#formid').serializeArray()
    .reduce((a, x) => ({ ...a, [x.name]: x.value }), {});
```

It will help for many of the 'normal' cases.

For the very common instance where there are multiple tags with duplicate `name` attributes, this is not enough.

Since inputs with duplicate `name` attributes are normally inside some 'wrapper' (`div`, `ul`, `tr`, ...), like in this exemple:

```
  <div class="wrapperClass">
    <input type="text" name="one">
    <input type="text" name="two">
  </div>
  <div class="wrapperClass">
    <input type="text" name="one">
    <input type="text" name="two">
  </div>
```

one can use reduce with the `map` operator to iterate on them:

```
$(".wrapperClass").map(function () {
  return $(this).find('*').serializeArray()
    .reduce((a, x) => ({ ...a, [x.name]: x.value }), {});
}).get();
```

The result will be an array of objects in the format:

```
  [
    {
      one: valueOfOne,
      two: valueOfTwo
    }, {
      one: valueOfOne,
      two: valueOfTwo
    }
  ]
```

The `.get()` operator is used in conjunction with `map` to get the basic array instead of the jQuery object which gives a cleaner result. [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript / jQuery one-liner-ish - which works on older versions too (pre ES6):

```
$('form').serializeArray().reduce((f,c) => {f[c['name']]=(f[c['name']])?[].concat(f[c['name']],c['value']):c['value']; return f}, {} );
```

Answer (score 1):

This uses the foreach method to iterate over the name and value pair returned by serializeArray and then return an object using the names as key.

```
  let formData = $(this).serializeArray();
  let formObject = {}
  formData.forEach(
    x=>formObject.hasOwnProperty(x.name)?formObject[x.name]=[formObject[x.name],x.value].flat():formObject[x.name]=x.value
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

For semantic-ui/fomantic-ui, there is a built-in behavior `get values`:

```
const fields = $("#myForm.ui.form").form('get values');
const jsonStr = JSON.stringify(fields);
```

See https://fomantic-ui.com/behaviors/form.html#/settings

> **get values(identifiers)**   Returns object of element values that match array of identifiers. If no IDS are passed will return all fields

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use this on a live site due to XSS attacks and probably plenty of other issues, but here's a quick example of what you could do:

```
$("#myform").submit(function(){
    var arr = $(this).serializeArray();
    var json = "";
    jQuery.each(arr, function(){
        jQuery.each(this, function(i, val){
            if (i=="name") {
                json += '"' + val + '":';
            } else if (i=="value") {
                json += '"' + val.replace(/"/g, '\\"') + '",';
            }
        });
    });
    json = "{" + json.substring(0, json.length - 1) + "}";
    // do something with json
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Couldn't you get around XSS attacks by converting them to JS object first, instead of directly to string?

Answer (score 0):

This is an improvement for Tobias Cohen's function, which works well with multidimensional arrays:

http://jsfiddle.net/BNnwF/2/

However, this is not a jQuery plugin, but it will only take a few seconds to make it into one if you wish to use it that way: simply replace the function declaration wrapper:

```
function serializeFormObject(form)
{
    ...
}
```

with:

```
$.fn.serializeFormObject = function()
{
    var form = this;
    ...
};
```

I guess it is similar to macek's solution in that it does the same thing, but i think this is a bit cleaner and simpler. I also included macek's test case inputs into the fiddle and added some additional ones. So far this works well for me.

```
function serializeFormObject(form)
{
    function trim(str)
    {
        return str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
    }

    var o = {};
    var a = $(form).serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        var nameParts = this.name.split('[');
        if (nameParts.length == 1) {
            // New value is not an array - so we simply add the new
            // value to the result object
            if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
                if (!o[this.name].push) {
                    o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                }
                o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
            } else {
                o[this.name] = this.value || '';
            }
        }
        else {
            // New value is an array - we need to merge it into the
            // existing result object
            $.each(nameParts, function (index) {
                nameParts[index] = this.replace(/\]$/, '');
            });

            // This $.each merges the new value in, part by part
            var arrItem = this;
            var temp = o;
            $.each(nameParts, function (index) {
                var next;
                var nextNamePart;
                if (index >= nameParts.length - 1)
                    next = arrItem.value || '';
                else {
                    nextNamePart = nameParts[index + 1];
                    if (trim(this) != '' && temp[this] !== undefined)
                        next = temp[this];
                    else {
                        if (trim(nextNamePart) == '')
                            next = [];
                        else
                            next = {};
                    }
                }

                if (trim(this) == '') {
                    temp.push(next);
                } else
                    temp[this] = next;

                temp = next;
            });
        }
    });
    return o;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My code from my library *phery* got a serialization routine that can deal with really complex forms (like in the demo https://github.com/pocesar/phery/blob/master/demo.php#L1664 ), and it's not a one-size-fits-all. It actually checks what the type of each field is. For example, a radio box isn't the same as a range, that isn't the same as keygen, that isn't the same as select multiple. My function covers it all, and you can see
it at https://github.com/pocesar/phery/blob/master/phery.js#L1851.

```js
serializeForm:function (opt) {
    opt = $.extend({}, opt);

    if (typeof opt['disabled'] === 'undefined' || opt['disabled'] === null) {
        opt['disabled'] = false;
    }
    if (typeof opt['all'] === 'undefined' || opt['all'] === null) {
        opt['all'] = false;
    }
    if (typeof opt['empty'] === 'undefined' || opt['empty'] === null) {
        opt['empty'] = true;
    }

    var
        $form = $(this),
        result = {},
        formValues =
            $form
                .find('input,textarea,select,keygen')
                .filter(function () {
                    var ret = true;
                    if (!opt['disabled']) {
                        ret = !this.disabled;
                    }
                    return ret && $.trim(this.name);
                })
                .map(function () {
                    var
                        $this = $(this),
                        radios,
                        options,
                        value = null;

                    if ($this.is('[type="radio"]') || $this.is('[type="checkbox"]')) {
                        if ($this.is('[type="radio"]')) {
                            radios = $form.find('[type="radio"][name="' + this.name + '"]');
                            if (radios.filter('[checked]').size()) {
                                value = radios.filter('[checked]').val();
                            }
                        } else if ($this.prop('checked')) {
                            value = $this.is('[value]') ? $this.val() : 1;
                        }
                    } else if ($this.is('select')) {
                        options = $this.find('option').filter(':selected');
                        if ($this.prop('multiple')) {
                            value = options.map(function () {
                                return this.value || this.innerHTML;
                            }).get();
                        } else {
                            value = options.val();
                        }
                    } else {
                        value = $this.val();
                    }

                    return {
                        'name':this.name || null,
                        'value':value
                    };
                }).get();

    if (formValues) {
        var
            i,
            value,
            name,
            $matches,
            len,
            offset,
            j,
            fields;

        for (i = 0; i < formValues.length; i++) {
            name = formValues[i].name;
            value = formValues[i].value;

            if (!opt['all']) {
                if (value === null) {
                    continue;
                }
            } else {
                if (value === null) {
                    value = '';
                }
            }

            if (value === '' && !opt['empty']) {
                continue;
            }

            if (!name) {
                continue;
            }

            $matches = name.split(/\[/);

            len = $matches.length;

            for (j = 1; j < len; j++) {
                $matches[j] = $matches[j].replace(/\]/g, '');
            }

            fields = [];

            for (j = 0; j < len; j++) {
                if ($matches[j] || j < len - 1) {
                    fields.push($matches[j].replace("'", ''));
                }
            }

            if ($matches[len - 1] === '') {
                offset = assign_object(result, fields, [], true, false, false);

                if (value.constructor === Array) {
                    offset[0][offset[1]].concat(value);
                } else {
                    offset[0][offset[1]].push(value);
                }
            } else {
                assign_object(result, fields, value);
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

It's part of my library *phery*, but it can be ported to your own project. It creates arrays where there should be arrays, it gets the correct selected options from the select, normalize checkbox options, etc. If you want to convert it to JSON (a real JSON string), just do `JSON.stringify($('form').serializeForm());`

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't here for you to promote your library.

Comment: ok but the the `serializeForm` is part of my library and does exactly what the OP wants

Comment: The last string is the best

Answer (score 0):

This solution is better. Some of the more popular options on here don't correct handle checkboxes when the checkbox is not checked.

```
getData: function(element){
//@todo may need additional logic for radio buttons
var select = $(element).find('select');
var input = $(element).find('input');
var inputs = $.merge(select,input);
var data = {};
//console.log(input,'input');
$.each(inputs,function(){
  if($(this).attr('type') != undefined){
    switch($(this).attr('type')){
     case 'checkbox':
        data[$(this).attr('name')] = ( ($(this).attr('checked') == 'checked') ? $(this).val():0 );
        break;
      default:
        data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
        break;
    }
  } 
  else {
    data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
  }
})
  return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a jQuery module, [jsForm](https://github.com/corinis/jsForm), that can do this bidirectional even for quite complicated forms (allows collections and other more complex structures as well).

It uses the name of the fields (plus a few special classes for collections) and matches a JSON object. It allows automatic replication of DOM-elements for collections and data handling:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://raw.github.com/corinis/jsForm/master/src/jquery.jsForm.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(function(){
            // Some JSON data
            var jsonData = {
                name: "TestName",   // Standard inputs
                description: "long Description\nMultiline", // Textarea
                links: [{href:'http://stackoverflow.com',description:'StackOverflow'}, {href:'http://www.github.com', description:'GitHub'}],   // Lists
                active: true,   // Checkbox
                state: "VISIBLE"    // Selects (enums)
            };

            // Initialize the form, prefix is optional and defaults to data
            $("#details").jsForm({
                data:jsonData
            });

            $("#show").click(function() {
                // Show the JSON data
                alert(JSON.stringify($("#details").jsForm("get"), null, " "));
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Simpel Form Test</h1>
        <div id="details">
            Name: <input name="data.name"/><br/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="data.active"/> active<br/>
            <textarea name="data.description"></textarea><br/>
            <select name="data.state">
                <option value="VISIBLE">visible</option>
                <option value="IMPORTANT">important</option>
                <option value="HIDDEN">hidden</option>
            </select>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Links</legend>
                <ul class="collection" data-field="data.links">
                    <li><span class="field">links.description</span> Link: <input name="links.href"/> <button class="delete">x</button></li>
                </ul>
            </fieldset>
            <button class="add" data-field="data.links">add a link</button><br/>
            Additional field: <input name="data.addedField"/>
        </div>
        <button id="show">Show Object</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending a form with JSON you must remove [] in sending the string. You can do that with the jQuery function serializeObject():

```
var frm = $(document.myform);
var data = JSON.stringify(frm.serializeObject());

$.fn.serializeObject = function() {
    var o = {};
    //var a = this.serializeArray();
    $(this).find('input[type="hidden"], input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="checkbox"]:checked, input[type="radio"]:checked, select').each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('type') == 'hidden') { //If checkbox is checked do not take the hidden field
            var $parent = $(this).parent();
            var $chb = $parent.find('input[type="checkbox"][name="' + this.name.replace(/\[/g, '\[').replace(/\]/g, '\]') + '"]');
            if ($chb != null) {
                if ($chb.prop('checked')) return;
            }
        }
        if (this.name === null || this.name === undefined || this.name === '')
            return;
        var elemValue = null;
        if ($(this).is('select'))
            elemValue = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        else
            elemValue = this.value;
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(elemValue || '');
        }
        else {
            o[this.name] = elemValue || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a form to a javascript object, then the easiest solution (at this time) is to use jQuery's `each` and `serializeArray` function-methods.

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function() {

  var form = {};
  $.each($(this).serializeArray(), function (i, field) {
    form[field.name] = field.value || "";
  });

  return form;
};
```

**Plugin hosted on GitHub:**
https://github.com/tfmontague/form-object/blob/master/README.md

**Can be installed with Bower:**
`bower install git://github.com/tfmontague/form-object.git`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non-jQuery way:

```
    var getFormData = function(form) {
        //Ignore the submit button
        var elements = Array.prototype.filter.call(form.elements, function(element) {
            var type = element.getAttribute('type');
            return !type || type.toLowerCase() !== 'submit';
        });
```

You can use it like this:

```
function() {

    var getFormData = function(form) {
        //Ignore the submit button
        var elements = Array.prototype.filter.call(form.elements, function(element) {
            var type = element.getAttribute('type');
            return !type || type.toLowerCase() !== 'submit';
        });

        //Make an object out of the form data: {name: value}
        var data = elements.reduce(function(data, element) {
            data[element.name] = element.value;
            return data;
        }, {});

        return data;
    };

    var post = function(action, data, callback) {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.onload = callback;
        request.open('post', action);
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        request.send(JSON.stringify(data), true);
        request.send();
    };

    var submit = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = e.target;
        var action = form.action;
        var data = getFormData(form);
        //change the third argument in order to do something
        //more intersting with the response than just print it
        post(action, data, console.log.bind(console));
    }

    //change formName below
    document.formName.onsubmit = submit;

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

This code working for me :

```
  var data = $('#myForm input, #myForm select, #myForm textarea').toArray().reduce(function (m, e) {
            m[e.name] = $(e).val();
            return m;
        }, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

This code convert and save type of inputs and not convert all to string:

```
jQuery.fn.serializeForm = function () {
    var form = this.get(0);
    var i = [];
    var ret = {};
    for (i = form.elements.length - 1; i >= 0; i = i - 1) {
        if (form.elements[i].name === "") {
            continue;
        }
        var name = form.elements[i].name;
        switch (form.elements[i].nodeName) {
            case 'INPUT':
                switch (form.elements[i].type) {
                    case 'text':
                    case 'tel':
                    case 'email':
                    case 'hidden':
                    case 'password':
                        ret[name] = encodeURIComponent(form.elements[i].value);
                        break;
                    case 'checkbox':
                    case 'radio':
                        ret[name] = form.elements[i].checked;
                        break;
                    case 'number':
                        ret[name] = parseFloat(form.elements[i].value);
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case 'SELECT':
            case 'TEXTAREA':
                ret[name] = encodeURIComponent(form.elements[i].value);
                break;
        }
    }
    return ret;
};
```

For example this is output:

```
Day: 13
Key: ""
Month: 5
OnlyPayed: true
SearchMode: "0"
Year: 2021
```

instead of

```
Day: "13"
Key: ""
Month: "5"
OnlyPayed: "true"
SearchMode: "0"
Year: "2021"
```

Answer (score 0):

This handles multiple select or even elements with the same name:

```
$.fn.formToJSON = function(){
    pairStr=this.serialize();
    let rObj={};
    pairStr.split(`&`).forEach((vp)=> {
        prop=vp.split(`=`)[0];
        val=vp.split(`=`)[1];
        if(rObj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            if (Array.isArray(rObj[prop])) {
                rObj[prop].push(val);
            } else {
                rObj[prop]=[rObj[prop]];
                rObj[prop].push(val);
            }
        } else {
            rObj[prop]=val;
        }
    });
    return JSON.stringify(rObj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*This thread seems to have become the collective FAQ for Form serialization :)*

My Take on the PHP-Naming: `<input name="user[name]" >`

```js
$('form').on('submit', function(ev) {
   ev.preventDefault();

   var obj = $(this).serializePHPObject();

   // $.post('./', obj);
});
```

```js
(function ($) {
  // based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/25239999/1644202

  // <input name="user[name]" >
  $.fn.serializePHPObject = function () {
    var obj = {};
    $.each(this.serializeArray(), function (i, pair) {
      var cObj = obj,
        pObj,
        cpName;
      $.each(pair.name.split("["), function (i, pName) {
        pName = pName.replace("]", "");
        pObj = cObj;
        cpName = pName;
        cObj = cObj[pName] ? cObj[pName] : (cObj[pName] = {});
      });
      pObj[cpName] = pair.value;
    });
    return obj;
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

### This will work exact same which you want

- Execute following code only once

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function(){
    let d={};
    $(this).serializeArray().forEach(r=>d[r.name]=r.value);
    return d;
}
```

- Now you can execute following line any number of times

```
let formObj = $('#myForm').serializeObject();
// will return like {id:"1", username:"abc"}
```

Comment: If the form include same name input fields only return the last one, =/

Answer (score 0):

That will take everything into consideration

```js
  function formToObject(form) {
    
    
    let data = new FormData(form);
    let queryString = new URLSearchParams(data).toString();
      var obj = {};
      var params = queryString.split("&");
      for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
        var param = params[i].split("=");
    
         var key = param[0].replace("[]", "");
         var key = key.replace("%5B%5D", "");
         
        var value = param[1];
        if (obj[key] === undefined) {
          obj[key] = value;
        } else if (obj[key] instanceof Array) {
          obj[key].push(value);
        } else {
          obj[key] = [obj[key], value];
        }
      }
      console.log(obj)
      return obj;
    }
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Form Example</title>
  </head>
  <body style="height:800px;overflow:scroll">
    <form id="test" onchange="formToObject(this)"><div><h3>fruits</h3>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="apple" id="apple">
<label for="apple">Apfel</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="banana" id="banana">
<label for="banana">Banane</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="cherry" id="cherry">
<label for="cherry">Kirsche</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="grape" id="grape">
<label for="grape">Traube</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="pear" id="pear">
<label for="pear">Birne</label></div>
<div><h3> multiple options</h3>
   
      <select multiple name="manyOptions[]">
        <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div><h3> Check on option</h3>
      <input type="radio" name="onceOption" value="Option 1">Option 1<br>
      <input type="radio" name="onceOption" value="Option 2">Option 2<br>
      <input type="radio" name="onceOption" value="Option 3">Option 3<br>
   
   </div></form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

The serialize function take JSON object as a parameter and return serialize String.

```
function serialize(object) {
            var _SPECIAL_CHARS = /[\\\"\x00-\x1f\x7f-\x9f\u00ad\u0600-\u0604\u070f\u17b4\u17b5\u200c-\u200f\u2028-\u202f\u2060-\u206f\ufeff\ufff0-\uffff]/g, _CHARS = {
                '\b' : '\\b',
                '\t' : '\\t',
                '\n' : '\\n',
                '\f' : '\\f',
                '\r' : '\\r',
                '"' : '\\"',
                '\\' : '\\\\'
            }, EMPTY = '', OPEN_O = '{', CLOSE_O = '}', OPEN_A = '[', CLOSE_A = ']', COMMA = ',', COMMA_CR = ",\n", CR = "\n", COLON = ':', space = "", COLON_SP = ': ', stack = [], QUOTE = '"';
            function _char(c) {
                if (!_CHARS[c]) {
                    _CHARS[c] = '\\u' + ('0000' + (+(c.charCodeAt(0))).toString(16))
                        .slice(-4);
                }
                return _CHARS[c];
            }
            function _string(s) {
                return QUOTE + s.replace(_SPECIAL_CHARS, _char) + QUOTE;
                // return str.replace('\"','').replace('\"','');
            }

            function serialize(h, key) {
                var value = h[key], a = [], colon = ":", arr, i, keys, t, k, v;
                arr = value instanceof Array;
                stack.push(value);
                keys = value;
                i = 0;
                t = typeof value;
                switch (t) {
                    case "object" :
                        if(value==null){
                            return null;
                        }
                        break;
                    case "string" :
                        return _string(value);
                    case "number" :
                        return isFinite(value) ? value + EMPTY : NULL;
                    case "boolean" :
                        return value + EMPTY;
                    case "null" :
                        return null;
                    default :
                        return undefined;
                }
                arr = value.length === undefined ? false : true;

                if (arr) { // Array
                    for (i = value.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
                        a[i] = serialize(value, i) || NULL;
                    }
                }
                else { // Object
                    i = 0;
                    for (k in keys) {
                        if (keys.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                            v = serialize(value, k);
                            if (v) {
                                a[i++] = _string(k) + colon + v;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                stack.pop();
                if (space && a.length) {

                    return arr
                        ? "[" + _indent(a.join(COMMA_CR), space) + "\n]"
                        : "{\n" + _indent(a.join(COMMA_CR), space) + "\n}";
                }
                else {
                    return arr ? "[" + a.join(COMMA) + "]" : "{" + a.join(COMMA)
                        + "}";
                }
            }
            return serialize({
                "" : object
            }, "");
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

This function returns all values converted to the right type;

bool/string/(integer/floats) possible

Tho you kinda need jQuery for this, but since serializeArray is jQuery too, so no big deal imho.

```
/**
 * serialized a form to a json object
 *
 * @usage: $("#myform").jsonSerialize();
 *
 */

(function($) {
    "use strict";
    $.fn.jsonSerialize = function() {
        var json = {};
        var array = $(this).serializeArray();
        $.each(array, function(key, obj) {
            var value = (obj.value == "") ? false : obj.value;
            if(value) {
                // check if we have a number
                var isNum = /^\d+$/.test(value);
                if(isNum) value = parseFloat(value);
                // check if we have a boolean
                var isBool = /^(false|true)+$/.test(value);
                if(isBool) value = (value!=="false");
            }
            json[obj.name] = value;
        });
        return json;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a map and cycle all fields, saving their values.

```
var params = {};
$("#form").find("*[name]").each(function(){
    params[this.getAttribute("name")] = this.value;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function serializedArray2Object(array){
    let obj = {};
    array.forEach(function(item){
        if(obj[item['name']] === undefined){
            obj[item['name']] = item['value'];
        }else if(Array.isArray(obj[item['name']])){
            obj[item['name']] = [...obj[item['name']],item['value']]
        }else{
            obj[item['name']] = [obj[item['name']],item['value']];
        }
    });
    return obj;
}
```

using

```js
serializedArray2Object($('#form').serializeArray())
```

I just discovered that function from jQuery and wrote a converter to object so the array becomes an object.

Answer (score -8):

Use this:

```
var sf = $('#mainForm').serialize(); // URL encoded string
sf = sf.replace(/"/g, '\"');         // Be sure all "s are escaped
sf = '{"' + sf.replace(/&/g, '","'); // Start "object", replace tupel delimiter &
sf = sf.replace(/=/g, '":"') + '"}'; // Replace equal sign, add closing "object"

// Test the "object"
var formdata = eval("(" + sf + ")"); 
console.log(formdata);
```

It works like a charm, even on very complex forms.

Comment: It is risky to `eval` user input - anything could happen. I strongly recommend to not do this.